# Laravel Validation Extension Regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am creating a Restful API on Laravel 5.6. After clients upload image, they send file path. I can validate using `mimes` while clients are uploading an image. After that i want to check file path extension using regex. But i have no idea how can i do ?

1.) Client send request -> upload_image (return image path) --> i am using `mimes`

2.) Client send request -> create_profile with image path --> i want to use `regex`

I dont know how regex write. Because i really hate regular expressions. I know, i shouldn't ask this question like. But i have to. Please help me ?

I want to control string : 'image-20180306.jpg', if last 3 char or after dot char is jpg, it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^.+\.jpe?g$
# ^     - match start of the string
# .+    - match 1+ chars
# \.    - a dot
# jpe?g - jpg or jpeg (? makes the predecessor optional)
# $     - the end of the string
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/5AEqoU/1/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation) with rule

```
'regex:/(\d)+.(?:jpe?g)/'
```